# Coverage Report Not Showning Up

Tags: .net, gitlab, cicd

I'm using GitLab free self-hosted, and I'm trying to get my coverage report showing up in my CICD pipeline. But I don't seem to get any luck with it. Below I have attached the code for the CICD pipeline that I currently have. if any someone any suggestion on what I may have done wrong or need to do. Let me know if more information is needed.

```
Unit_Test:
  stage: Test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
  services:
  - mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
  script:
    - 'dotnet test Test/ApiUnitTesting/ApiUnitTesting.csproj --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=../artifacts/ApiUnitTesting-test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"'
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./**/*test-result.xml
      - ./**/coverage.cobertura.xml
    reports:
      cobertura:
        - ./**/coverage.cobertura.xml
      junit:
        - ./**/*test-result.xml
```

Comment: Can you download the job artifacts and confirm `coverage.cobertura.xml` appears in your job artifacts?

Comment: @sytech yes i can download it from the job artifacts

Comment: Have you configured your project or pipeline to read your coverage report? You have to set the regex for your test library either in your Project's settings or in the Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline file. See [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#add-test-coverage-results-using-coverage-keyword) for more.